# TypeScript: Functions are assignable but produces error if target parameter type is not assignable to source parameter type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example: (In strict-null-checks) mode

```
const fn: (p: { x: number } | null) => void = (p: { x: number }) => console.log(p.x);
fn(null);
```

This code produces no errors in typescript, but has a runtime type exception.

Seems to me like Typescript should have enforced target parameter type (here `{x: number } | null`) to be assignable to source parameter type (here `{ x: number }`), so that, for example null wouldn't be passed where something else was expected and cause an error.

Why is this not enforcing that? Is that a bug in typescript? Or something in the configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: I get an error in Typescript with your code https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAXDAFAB2QbxgD2WAVwFsAjAUwCcYBfGAHxkIBsmBKGAXgD4YA3EAJYATTqgwxseRsXJVq7bjFCQQTMgDomIAObp1OVgG4AUAhTM2hoA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default function parameters relate bi-variantly. This means that if the function is assignable if either the target parameter is a subtype of the source parameter or vice-versa (which is why this succeeds since `{ x: number }` is a subtype of `{ x: number }  | null`

If you enable `strictFunctionTypes` parameters will relate contravariantly, this will mean that the assignment will succeed only if the target parameter is a subtype of source parameter. This will produce an error here since `{ x: number } | null` is not a subtype of `{ x: number }`

Enable `strictFunctionTypes` and you will get an error. You can see this behavior in the playground too: [with the option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAXDAFAB2QbxgD2WAVwFsAjAUwCcYBfGAHxkIBsmBKGAXgD4YA3EAJYATTqgwxseRsXJVq7bjFCQQTMgDomIAObp1OVgG4AUAhTM2hoA) and [without the option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictFunctionTypes=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAXDAFAB2QbxgD2WAVwFsAjAUwCcYBfGAHxkIBsmBKGAXgD4YA3EAJYATTqgwxseRsXJVq7bjFCQQTMgDomIAObp1OVgG4AUAhTM2hoA)